# Events change back to default values in OSX Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar

I have a problem with my Calendar on my Mac OSX 10.9.5.
I normally double click on any date and create a new event. I give it an appropriate name and the correct time and after 2 to 5 seconds some of my settings are reset to the default value. So the time is set again to all day event, or the title is set to "New Event" or other things are just lost.

These are all iCloud calendars. It looks a little bit like the sync with the cloud is not working properly. Like on double click it creates an event and sync it to iCloud. After my edits, it doesn't get synced into the cloud, but after a few seconds it gets the already since event (with default settings) from the iCloud and overwrites my changes to the event. 
(not sure if this is really the case, it is just my theory)

I search this community already and found a similar problem which was closed due to low quality answers but in the end, there was no suggestion at all. ([similar article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190225/ical-events-changed-to-default-new-event-on-macbook))

So my work around is do just one step at the time, changing time, name, etc, but even this is not always working and it is really annoying.

On my iphone, everything works fine without an issue.

Thanks in advance for any hints tips and tricks.

Comment: Did you try logging out and signing back into icloud on your mac already? If that doesn't work, then try this solution [here](https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12386508) and see if it works.

Comment: and this is new, it worked before ?

Comment: @azngeoffdog you can log out and in from iCloud?! Have to test this. The other solution is a bit scary, I am afraid to loose data...

Comment: @Buscar웃SD yes it is new. It worked like 3 months before. Not sure if I did an update or something. I recognised it once, then it seems to work, and now it is almost every time.

Comment: Way back when, Google sync used to have rules for how it handled mismatches between desktop and web-based calendar. I checked for similar settings in iCloud or Calendar. Maybe someone else is aware of them?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD disconsolate or switching of the phone didn't help.